# How can I share multiple Docker caches between Jenkins pipeline runs?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I have a Jenkins pipeline using the kubernetes plugin to run a [docker in docker](https://github.com/docker-library/docker/blob/65fab2cd767c10f22ee66afa919eda80dbdc8872/18.09/dind/Dockerfile) container and build images:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      label 'kind'
      defaultContainer 'jnlp'
      yaml """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    name: dind
...
```

I also have a pool of persistent volumes in the jenkins namespace each labelled `app=dind`. I want one of these volumes to be picked for each pipeline run and used as `/var/lib/docker` in my dind container in order to cache any image pulls on each run. I want to have a pool and caches, not just a single one, as I want multiple pipeline runs to be able to happen at the same time. How can I configure this?

This can be achieved natively in kubernetes by creating a persistent volume claim as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: dind
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: dind
```

and mounting it into the Pod, but I'm not sure how to configure the pipeline to create and cleanup such a persistent volume claim.

Comment: Have you checked https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/ ?

Comment: @AmritBera I'm familiar with them yeah, but not too sure how they would help here?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think the way you think it can be achieved natively in kubernetes - wouldn't work. You either have to re-use same PVC which will make build pods to access same PV concurrently, or if you want to have a PV per build - your PVs will be stuck in `Released` status and not automatically available for new PVCs.

There is more details and discussion available here https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-42422.

It so happens that I wrote two simple controllers - automatic PV releaser (that would find and make `Released` PVs `Available` again for new PVCs) and dynamic PVC provisioner (for Jenkins Kubernetes plugin specifically - so you can define a PVC as annotation on a Pod). Check it out here https://github.com/plumber-cd/kubernetes-dynamic-reclaimable-pvc-controllers. There is a full `Jenkinsfile` example here https://github.com/plumber-cd/kubernetes-dynamic-reclaimable-pvc-controllers/tree/main/examples/jenkins-kubernetes-plugin-with-build-cache.